# Function can't seem to print out error message

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I wrote this small function in my .zshrc file to make moving back in the directory tree faster:

```bsh
#: Move back x director(y/ies).
function bak ()
{
    local x=""
    local limit="$1"
    local msg="Can't move back $limit directories"
    [ -z "$limit" ] && limit=1
    for ((i=0;i<limit;i++)); do
        x="../$x"
    done
    if ! cd "$x"; then
        echo "$msg";
    fi
}
```

It works just fine except for 2 caveats:

1. While the function runs and I can move back in the directory tree, if I ever try to move past the limit (root "/") the function doesn't print out the error message. So basically this part

   ```bsh
   if ! cd "$x"; then
       echo "$msg";
   fi
   ```

   just doesn't do anything.
2. If I remove that part (the if statement to print error message), the function no longer works.

---

**Can anyone help me get the error message part to work, please?** Also if anyone can explain why removing the error message part breaks the function that would be great.

Comment: There's a `..` entry in the root directory, pointing right back to the root directory (run `ls -lid / /. /..`, and you'll see that all three have the same inode number, i.e. they're all the exact same thing). Also, when you removed the `if` statement, did you remove the `cd` along with it?

Comment: @Gordon Davisson yeah I removed the entire if statement (from if to fi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most systems the `/..` path refers to the same file as `/`, the root directory. [That's allowed though not required by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_13):

> The special filename dot-dot shall refer to the parent
> directory of its predecessor directory. As a special case, in the root
> directory, dot-dot may refer to the root directory itself.

Even on systems where `/..` is not the same as `/`, as you're calling `cd` without `-P`, that defaults to `cd -L` where the shell does a *logical* `cd`,  whereby when `$PWD` is  `/a/b/c` (where `/a`, `/a/b` or `/a/b/c` could very well be symbolic links to other directories) and you do `cd ../..` for instance, instead of doing `chdir("../..")`, `cd` does `chdir("/a")` and if you do `cd ../../../../../../..`, `cd` does a `chdir("/")` (as [required by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html)).

Also note that error messages should go to stderr:

```
bak() {
    local x limit="${1-1}"
    repeat "$limit" x+=../
    cd "$x" && return
    local ret=$?
    print -u2 "Can't cd back $limit directories"
    return "$ret"
}
```

Though that message is likely to be superfluous as if `cd` failed it will already have written an error message.

If you want to return failure if `bak` is given a limit greater than the number of components in `$PWD`, you can do:

```
bak() {
  local depth=0 dir=$PWD x
  repeat "${1-1}" {
    if [[ $dir = / ]]; then
      print -u2 "The current working directory is only $depth level deep"
      return 1
    fi
    dir=$dir:h x+=../
    ((depth++))
  }
  cd "$x"
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply I had to run some errands just now. Thank you so much for such a great answer (and links to the documentation are the cherries on top!). I'll be reading up on the docs for now. Thank you again!